# How to insert a default item in drop down and disable it using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I've 3 drop downs, after the selecting the value for first drop down, I'm populating the second drop down using jQuery and ajax. What I want is to have a default item for the second drop down like *Select a value*.

Here is my jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function (){ 
             $(".dropdown").change(function(event){
                 var name = $("#doctype").val();
                 $.ajax({
                     url:'ServiceToFetchSubType',
                     data: {name:name},
                     type:'post',
                     cache:false,
                     success: function(response){

                         var select = $('#docsubtype');
                         select.find('option').remove();
                         $.each(response, function(index, value){
                             $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                         });
                         callback.apply(select);
                     }


                 });


             });         


         });
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
          $(".dropdown1").change(function(event){
              var name = $("#doctype").val();
              var name2 = $("docsubtype").val();
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'ServiceToFetchDocUnit',
                  data: {"name":name, "name1":name2},
                  type: 'post',
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(response)
                  {
                     var select = $('#docunit');
                     select.find('option').remove();
                     $.append($('<option>',{value: -1, text: "Select Doc Subtype"}))
                     $.each(response, function(index, value){
                         $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                     });
                     callback.apply(select);

                  }
              });
          });

      });
      </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                <select name="doctype" id="doctype" class="my_dropdown" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Type</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${bt}" var="doctypes">
                                     <option><c:out value="${doctypes}"/></option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown1">
                                <select name="doctype" id="docsubtype" class="my_dropdown1" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc SubType</option>
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown2">
                                <select name="doctype" id="docunit" class="my_dropdown2" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Unit</option>
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </header>


                <!-- Main -->


                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <p class="copyright">&copy; Design: Content Management OPS</p>
                    </footer>

            </div>

        <!-- BG -->
            <div id="bg"></div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty new to jQuery and AJAX, any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("#docsubtype")[0].options.length=1` Will KEEP the first option and remove the rest - use it instead of `select.find("options").remove`

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean by "remove the rest"? I'm sorry I didn't get you. What I want is like **<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc SubType</option>** then have the list for the dropdown

Comment: I know. Try my code. It will LEAVE the one you wrote in the HTML and your appends will just add the new ones after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
$('<option value="">Select a value</option>').appendTo(select);
```

Before

```
$.each(response, function(index, value){
```

Comment: @Zeus07  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

To keep the first option before appending new ones, simply change

`select.find('option').remove();` to

`select[0].options.length=1;`

which will remove all options from the second to the end before the new appends leaving

```
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc SubType</option>
```